# General linear model

Tags: r

I' like to run the ff. GLM:

```
Sb <- matrix(c(1,5), nrow = 2)
Db <- matrix(c(10/9, 10/9, 10/9, 20/3, 40/9, 30/9), nrow = 3)
Db_Transponiert <- t(Db)
DbInv <-solve(Db_Transponiert)
DbInv
DbInv %*% Sb
```

By doing so, I get the ff. error-message:
Error in solve.default(Db_Transponiert) : 
  only quadratic matrizes can be inverted.

Doing it by "hand" one gets a solution, namely: (x, 1.8-3x, -0.9+2x), with x in the interval (0.45, 0.6).
Matlab, which I do not use, but which is the preferred tool at Stochastic Depart. at Hannover-Uni., produces the a/m vector as a solution.
Q: Could anyone please help me with the programming code in R?
Thanks,
Andreas
PS: Trust that this Q. is okay under Cross Validated???

Comment: Your problem is that `Db` is not a square matrix, so does not possess an inverse.  (Not sure why your error message refers to "quadratic" matrices.)  R is not an algebraic solver, and can't give you solutions that refer to unknowns, like (x, 1.8-3x, -0.9+2x).

Comment: What does "ff" mean?

Comment: I think we could help you if you took a step back and explained in what sense this is a GLM.  In the statistics world (and it flows through into how R is coded) people think in terms of a response variable which will be a vector with n elements, and a number (let's say r) of explanatory variables each of which will be a vector or which can be thought of as an n x r matrix.

Comment: Peter, thanks for comments, ff = following, "Sb"=pricevector for share prices (here two), "Db" is a matrix for the number of shares, -here three-, hence I'd like to solve: Db(transpose; known)*x(unknown vector, looking for: x1, x2, x3) = Sb (vector, known).  My program runs until "Db_Transponiert <- t(Db)" and produces an error at line "DbInv <-solve(Db_Transponiert)" jbowman is right with his/her comment, but if there is a chance to solve this "small" problem in R, your help would be very much appreciated. Andreas

Comment: Thanks, that's clearer, although I don't understand what interest there is in the x vector.  I voted to close as I don't think this is a statistical question (and, for example, you are using "general linear model" in a different sense to how statisticians do); but see my answer below.

Comment: This is not how one fits a linear model of any sort: the equation is incorrect (nonsensical, actually, which is why `R` complains about a non-*square* matrix). For the correct equations, see a textbook or an online resource like [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_%28mathematics%29#Computation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R isn't designed for given an algebraic answer to a system of equations with more unknowns than equations.  The package [Ryacas](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Ryacas/) gives an interface from R to the "Yet Another Computer Algebra System" and I think could probably do this for you, but I wouldn't say this is R's comparative advantage.